# An example of an open ball whose closure is strictly between it and the corresponding closed ball

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Does there exist a metric space $M$, such that there exists a point $x$ and a positive real number $r$, for which the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$ is a proper subset of its closure, and the closure in turn is a proper subset of the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Consider $X = \{-1\} \cup [0,1]$, with the distance coming from the absolute value.

Then:

1. the open ball centred at $0$ of radius $1$ is $B(0,1) = [0,1)$,
2. its closure is $\overline{B(0,1)} = [0,1]$,
3. and the closed ball centred at $0$ of radius $1$ is $\bar{B}(0,1)= \{-1\}\cup [0,1] = X$.

We then have the strict inclusions $B(0,1) \subsetneq \overline{B(0,1)} \subsetneq \bar{B}(0,1)$.

One can even ask for $X$ to be connected.
For instance, let $X$ be the red curve in the following picture, endowed with the induced metric from the Euclidean plane, $x$ the origin, and $r=1$.
[image: a connected example]

Comment: FTR, there's no need for the curve to be so edgy: a single arc from the origin to $(-1,0)$ would also work, so long as it has a length $>\frac\pi2$.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I wanted the arc to be the exact analogue of the $1$-dimensional example I gave before (here, one just has to replace the sets $A$ with $A\times\{0\}$), but sure, you are right

Comment: It is also clear how the example from the first sentence of the answer can be turned into a _countable_ metric space with the property, namely $X=\{-1\} \cup \left\{ 1-\frac{1}{n} \mid n\in\mathbb{N} \right\} \cup \{ 1 \}$.